# Silex default_target_path not working after successful login

Tags: forms, symfony, redirect, authentication, silex

I've got a problem ith redirect after successful login.

App.php file (part of it):

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;
/** ... */
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PlaintextPasswordEncoder;

$app = new Application();
/** ... */

$app['security.encoder.digest'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new PlaintextPasswordEncoder();
});

$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/admin/',
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/admin/login_check',
            'default_target_path' => '/admin/news',
            'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
        ),
        'users' => array(
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'test'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

My controllers.php file:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig', array(
        'error' => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
});

$app->get('/admin/news', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    if ($app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        echo 'admin';
    }
});
```

I am logged in (after passing correct login data in form), I have access to /admin/news route, but I have to go to that address manually. I'd like to be redirected there automatically after successful login. Now I'm kept in /login page. When I change default_target_path to 'http://google.com', it works properly.

I use homestead (vagrant) with nginx. Silex 1.3.0.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (or rather workaround) which worked was:

- change `'default_target_path'` to `'/admin';`
- add new route:

  `$app->get('/admin', function() use ($app) {
      return $app['twig']->render('admin/loggedIn.html.twig');
  });`
- in `admin/loggedIn.html.twig` template I've added js redirect to `admin/news`

I don't have any idea why wasn't it working. If anyone knows - please leave a comment.

Comment: there's alot of possibilities, could be you have required parameters for that method or a specific role